# Drools - Grouping multiple dsl conditions in dslr's when part throws error

Tags: drools, dsl, rules, rule-engine

Am creating a small rule engine and using drools for it. My design is like the developer (that's me :)) will develop dsl and a business user can create rules (dslr).

**dsl file**

```
[When]When [Pp]urchase amount is greater than "{Value}" = e : Event(EventAction.isPurchaseGreaterThan(e,{Value}))
[When]If [Cc]ustomer tier equals to "{CustomerTier}"=e1 : Event(EventAction.isCustomerTierEqualTo(e1,"{CustomerTier}")
[Then]Give "{Discount}" Percentage Discount = RewardAction.applyDiscount(e, {Discount});
[Then]Suggest Redemption = System.out.println("Redemption Suggested");
```

**dslr file**

```
rule "Discount For Purchase-1"
    when (When purchase amount is greater than "100") && (If customer tier equals to "Silver")
    then     #Error is thrown in this line
        Give "5" Percentage Discount 
end
```

The rest of the java code is similar to the one given in examples. In this code am getting the following error

**Error**

```
Line 15:4 mismatched input 'then' in rule "Discount For Purchase-1"
```

Whereas the below dslr works fine

```
rule "Discount For Purchase-1"
    when (When purchase amount is greater than "100")
    then
        Give "5" Percentage Discount 
end
```

**Generated DRL**

```
when (e : Event(EventAction.isPurchaseGreaterThan(e,100))) && (e : Event(EventAction.isCustomerTierEqualTo(e,"Silver"))
```

**Note on this Generated DRL** - I might get duplicate variable error for 'e'. That's another problem. But just to sort out this problem i've even tried modifing the second variable to 'e1' in dsl.

And for your information i've tried the below to resolve the error, but noting helped me out

```
When (When purchase amount is greater than "100" && If customer tier equals to "Silver")
When (When purchase amount is greater than "100" and If customer tier equals to "Silver")
When ((When purchase amount is greater than "100") && (If customer tier equals to "Silver"))
When ((When purchase amount is greater than "100") and (If customer tier equals to "Silver"))
When ((When purchase amount is greater than "100") and (If customer tier equals to "Silver"));
When ((When purchase amount is greater than "100") && (If customer tier equals to "Silver"));
```

**Update :**

**Generated drl**

```
=== DRL xpanded from DSLR ===
   1  #created on: 5 Oct, 2016
   2  package com.test.loyalty.rules
   3  
   4  #list any import classes here.
   5  import com.test.loyalty.*
   6  import com.test.loyalty.model.*
   7  import com.test.loyalty.util.*
   8  
   9  
  10  
  11  #declare any global variables here
  12  
  13  rule "Discount For Purchase-1"
  14      when 
  15        e : Event(EventAction.isPurchaseGreaterThan(e,100))
  16        e1 : Event(EventAction.isCustomerTierEqualTo(e1,"Silver")
  17      then
  18          System.out.println("Redemption Suggested"); 
  19  end
  20  
  21  rule "Discount For Purchase-2"
  22      when
  23          e : Event(EventAction.isPurchaseGreaterThan(e,100))
  24        e1 : Event(EventAction.isCustomerTierEqualTo(e1,"Gold")
  25      then
  26          System.out.println("Redemption Suggested"); 
  27  end
  28  


=============================
[ERR 102] Line 17:4 mismatched input 'then' in rule "Discount For Purchase-1"
17
[ERR 102] Line 25:4 mismatched input 'then' in rule "Discount For Purchase-2"
25
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse knowledge.
    at com.test.loyalty.LoyaltyTest.readKnowledgeBase(LoyaltyTest.java:124)
    at com.test.loyalty.LoyaltyTest.init(LoyaltyTest.java:104)
    at com.test.loyalty.LoyaltyTest.main(LoyaltyTest.java:38)
```

can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are about to combine two patterns (using class EventAction) at top level, so no operator is necessary, and `&&` would be wrong for combining patterns anyway - it is available for constraints within patterns.

```
rule "Discount For Purchase-1"
when
    When purchase amount is greater than "100"
    If customer tier equals to "Silver"
then    
    Give "5" Percentage Discount 
end
```

I wonder whether you have indeed the combination of two Event-s in mind. If not, it's better to combine the constraints within one pattern - although this is a bit tricky. (See the doc.) Alternatively, you can indeed force the identity of another fact bound to a second pattern (of the same class) by using something like `this == e` in an additional constraint.

**Edit**
Now that you have added the expanded text, it stands out: Event(EventAction.isCustomerTierEqualTo(e1,"Silver") misses a closing parenthesis at the end, same thing in the other rule. Fix the substitution rule in the DSL.

You can use the same variable(s) in any number of rules, but you cannot bind two patterns within the same rule to the same variable. You may have to redesign your DSL a little, e.g.

```
# creates the Person pattern and binds $person
[condition][]There is a Person with=$person:Person()

# write a comparison using a field reference and a value
[condition][]- his {field} {operator} {value}=
             {field} {operator} {value}
```

The DSLR becomes:

```
when
    There is a Person with
    - his call_count is less than 10 or name is equal to "Joe" 
    - his points is greater than 5
then
```

expands to

```
when
    $person:Person(call_count  <  10 || name == "Joe", points  >  5)
then
```

Of course, you'll need the definitions for the operators (or your functions)

```
[condition][]is greater than=>
[condition][]is equal to===
```

The initial hyphen is essential, and you need something ("his" or "her") in front of the first parameter (`{field}`).

Comment: Sorry it didn't help, And yes the rules in when conditions are intended to be that way. As specified in my dsl there are many independent rules which can be clubbed in anyway possible ways (one to other).

Comment: It works - perhaps you have some other syntax error. Put `#/ result` as the first line into your .dsl file to see the expanded rule and check error messages. If it still doesn't work, edit your question showing what you have after the changes and the error message. - Note that you'll have to omit the second binding, and this will only work if you have exactly one Event fact in working memory when rules are fired.

Comment: Kindly check the updated part. Thanks for your support, but still i face the same problem.

Comment: Now it stands out: `Event(EventAction.isCustomerTierEqualTo(e1,"Silver")` misses a closing parenthesis at the end, same thing in the other rule. Fix the substitution rule in the DSL.

Comment: That's right!! :) Thanks a lot and such a stupid mistake i've made. Feeling embarrassed. But an explanatory error message from drools could be useful in this case. Anyway, Could you update this in your answer so i could mark your answer as the right one to this question? Also kindly tell me if i can use the same variable in both the rules. it throws duplicate variable error. The problem is i need to enable business user to use any rules in mix and match form, and the same applies for then part too. so using the object in then becomes complicated if i use a different variable names in when part

Comment: And FYI this Event object will be the data for all my rules. Any possibilities or hacks i can try out? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with the quotes "" in your value 100. Try rewriting as

```
When]When [Pp]urchase amount is greater than {Value} = = e : Event(EventAction.isPurchaseGreaterThan(e,"{Value}"));
```

And when writing your rule there is no need to insert quotes. Of course this is true if your Value is String. If it is an int exclude the quotes. another advice in order to see your rules transated you should insert

`/# debug: display result`

in the start and in the end of your dsl file.

Comment: sorry to disappoint you, "" quotes is not the problem. I've tried simple rules with quotes and without quotes for all data types. Actually quotes has nothing to do with data type. I've put quotes is for more readability to business user, so he can modify all those quoted values in a dslr file. That's the point i wanted to make. Also this one " /# debug: display result", where do i need to give. I put this in dsl file and it didn't work.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html_single/#d0e7849.    4.10.5 section has a list of debug options.. Also what i say about quotes is that you have them both in your rules and in your dsl dictionary file. Maybe there is a conflict.

Comment: You have a debugger my mistake. Now what i think thaat it is wrong is that you have to put the quotes only in the right hand of the equality of your dsl file. In your case there are quotes in the left hand of your dsl file and in your dslr too. That value "100" maps to an entity and extra quotes are put according to your dsl.